# How do you get window titles, ids, and names in selenium-webdriver?

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver

Im trying to implement the following methods from **selenium-webdriver** (ruby)

- get_all_window_ids
- get_all_window_titles
- get_all_window_names

1. I ran Selenium IDE and exported my script to Ruby Test::Unit. Saved it as .rb
2. Opened my script for editing using Aptana Studio 3
3. Initial code snippet as follows:

```
require "rubygems"
require "selenium-webdriver"
require "test/unit"

class SwitchToPopup3 < Test::Unit::TestCase

  def setup
    @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
    @base_url = (URL of my test website)
    @driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 30
    @verification_errors = []
  end

  def teardown
    @driver.quit
    assert_equal [], @verification_errors
  end


def test_switch_to_popup3
  .
  .
  puts @driver.get_all_window_ids()
  puts @driver.get_all_window_titles()
  puts @driver.get_all_window_names()
  .
  .
end
```

The error I keep getting is

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `get_all_window_ids' for #    <Selenium::WebDriver::Driver:0x101e4b040 browser=:chrome>
/Users/rsucgang/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/Testing/SwitchToPopup2.rb:37:in `test_switch_to_popup3'
```

I've studied the documentation for the ruby bindings for selenium-webdriver

http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/Client/GeneratedDriver.html#get_all_window_titles-instance_method

Ultimately my goal here is to run my automation script:

1. Click on a link that opens a new window with target=_blank and no windowID available (does not implement JS)
2. Identify the names of all opened windows in the browser
3. switch to a new pop-up window using the switchToWindow(name) method
4. continue running my script on that pop-up window

I've googled and researched this on the internet and I have not gotten any much information.

Thanks and please let me know if you need more information.

- OSL Mac OSX 10.7.3
- Ruby: ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [universal-darwin11.0]
- Browser: Firefox 9.0.1 (Mac)
- Chrome: Chrome 17.0.963.79 (Mac)
- Selenium-Server: Ruby gem 2.20.0

Comment: +1, I've rarely seen such a well documented first post on SA.

Comment: Just a minor edit. The error message contains "browser=:chrome" whereas my code indicated the driver is for :firefox. I pasted the error code when I ran the :chrome instance. Regardless, both browser drivers will still yield the same noMethodError message.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that the `get_all_window_ids` is for Selenium::Client rather than Selenium::Webdriver. I believe that Selenium::Client is the old version Selenium and the API is not the same as Selenium::Webdriver (see [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RubyBindings#-backed_Selenium)). Since you are using Selenium::Webdriver, this explains why you get an 'undefined method' error.

For Selenium::Webdriver, the only way I know how to switch between windows is using:

```
@driver.switch_to.window("<window_handle>")
```

You can get all the known window_handles by:

```
@driver.window_handles
#=> Returns all window handles as an array of strings
```

If you want to switch to the popup you just opened you can do the following. Note that this assumes `.window_handles` are in the order that the windows were opened, which I believe is true:

```
@driver.switch_to.window @driver.window_handles.last
```

To summarize, assuming you only care about accessing the popup (and not about accessing by name) you can do:

```
#Click control that opens popup
@driver.find_element(:id, 'button that opens popup').click
#Switch to popup
@driver.switch_to.window @driver.window_handles.last
#Do actions in new popup
@driver.find_element(:id, 'id of element in popup').click
```

Note that if after working with the popup, you will want to return to the original window, then I suggest you do the following. By passing a block to the `switch_to.window`, the block will be executed in the popup and when the block ends `@driver` will automatically point back to the original window.

```
#Click control that opens popup
@driver.find_element(:id, 'button that opens popup').click
#Switch to popup
@driver.switch_to.window( @driver.window_handles.last ){
  #Do actions in new popup
  @driver.find_element(:id, 'id of element in popup').click
}
#Continue with original window
@driver.find_element(:id, 'button in original window').click
```

Comment: Thank you Justin! Your explanation makes sense. I just tried it and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 11):

Justin, you have a good approach. But there is a gotcha in assuming that the window handles will return in the correct order. This isn't always the case across all browsers. I outline a slightly different approach in my free weekly Selenium tip newsletter (elemental-selenium.com).

It goes like this:

```
@driver.get 'http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/windows'
main_window = @driver.window_handle
@driver.find_element(css: '.example a').click
windows = @driver.window_handles
  windows.each do |window|
    if main_window != window
      @new_window = window
    end
  end
@driver.switch_to.window(main_window)  
@driver.title.should_not =~ /New Window/  
@driver.switch_to.window(@new_window)  
@driver.title.should =~ /New Window/
```

You can see the full tip [here](http://elemental-selenium.com/tips/4-work-with-multiple-windows).

Comment: Nice! I can't believe this didn't get more up votes!