# Keep focus on pop up with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am running an automated script with Selenium Webdriver (Ruby). At some point I need to click on `myelement` that, as result, will open a pop up (new modal browser window).

However, the focus of the script (`browser` variable) is still on the original browser window and not in the pop up. How can I keep the focus on the pop up?

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
browser.navigate.to 'http://example.com'
browser.find_element(:id, 'myelement').click # Opens pop up and returns nil
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like

```
@browser.switch_to.window(@browser.window_handles.last)
```

The accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9705814/3456626) has a really good explanation of how to use switch_to.