# How can I target a new popup window, rather than a tab using Selenium?

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

For the moment I have been using the following to essentially check that a new tab has opened, and then switch to that tab:

```
@wait.until{@driver.window_handles.length > 1}
@driver.switch_to.window(@driver.window_handles[1])  where 1 is the tab number
```

I wanted to know how to use something similar like the above, but for ***windows*** where this window is an iFrame, using Webdriver.

I need to supply some details in an iframe, and then switch back to the main window (although once the details are submitted the iframe will close and I should be redirected back to the main window I had earlier so this should be automatic I think)

To be clear also, I am using the Ruby binding of Selenium.

Comment: Which Selenum Binding are you using? Java / Python / C#

Comment: @DebanjanB I am using the Ruby binding

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get window titles, ids, and names in selenium-webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692460/how-do-you-get-window-titles-ids-and-names-in-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: Your question is confusing... you are talking about windows and iframes... which is it? If you aren't sure, do some research on the difference between them and come back and edit the question with the results of your research. Also please post the code that you have tried and the results.

Comment: @JeffC the iframe opens in a new window, so from my perspective they're the same? I just need to switch to it

Comment: They aren't the same... windows are not iframes. You would have to switch driver context to the new window and then switch into the iframe before you could start to get to the elements you want. These concepts are all well explained in many places on SO and elsewhere. Take the time to learn about each and write some code attempting this and update your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to locate something inside an iframe, before you have to switch to the interested iframe. For example, in Java, if you can identify the iframe by id:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("idframe")));
```

Finally, to return back:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

I never used ruby but, from [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Ruby-Bindings) should be:

```
# switch to a frame
driver.switch_to.frame "some-frame" # id
```

and

```
# switch back to the main document
driver.switch_to.default_content
```